# Can you run a website anonymously?

Tags: forum, payments, privacy, adult-content

**Can you run a Website anonymously?**

Say you wanted to run a website, but want to keep your identity private. This could be because of reasons such as hosting adult content, journalism, or providing a service that's legal but you don't want being traced back to you.

1. How can I pay for webhosting
2. How do I manage domain privacy such as whois
3. How can I accept donations/payment and still be able to withdraw funds without claiming them as coming from X service.

Comment: You can keep things private from the general public, but you can't keep things private from domain registries or whoever you pay for the hosting...unless they happen to accept a crypto currency.

Comment: Google "privacy domain registration", there are services out there that let you register domains anonymously. For payments, use cryptocurrency. Good luck.

Comment: Questions here really need to be limited to single [reasonably scoped](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) issue or problem.

Comment: ive modified the question to fix the formatting and to try and make it fix more within the guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you run a website anonymously?

Yes you can.

*Lets first put the caveat out that there are legitimate reasons to want to do so. I think it's easy for some to instantly conflate wanting to host or provide a service online anonymously as a means that they must be doing something illegal and that of course is just not the case. A perfect example would be certain types of journalism.*

---

**Now onto answering some of your questions...**

> Terms of payments

Using some form of crypto currency or by using a prepaid credit card. You can easily buy prepaid credit cards with cash from gas stations or even grocery stores.

> whois queries

This is where you will want to find a domain provider who offers a privacy domain registration service. This isn't the place to directly recommend providers however I am unaware of others beside Njalla. But when seeking a provider make sure that they are actually offering privacy services. In the njalla example they offer more of a registration by proxy type method.

> Donations / Income

Here you can use crypto again, however this would require that the people you wish to get donations from can actually pay you in some form of crypto. There are multiple crypto payment gateways which offer a withdrawal method such as paypal or direct deposit.

---

**Now just some closing notes:**

- You can not assume a provider who accepts crypto payments is doing it as a means as offering some sort of privacy service other then just trying to accept more forms of payment in general. There are providers who actually do offer more private services as in they don't require much information from you other than some sort of contact method like an email address.
- The content of which you host must still actually be legal for the provider. These providers are still governed by many other external factors.